# How to embed an application(by specifying url) in iFrame portlet

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, portlet

I am trying to develop iFrame in portlets (aim is to embed an application which should come up, on clicking the portlet), using Eclipse 3.7 IDE. I have started recently and have understood what portlet is. Can anyone please enlighten me on **what iframe is** and **how it can be used to develop/embed(by giving url) an application** in this iframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to know how to add iframe(access any website/app) in the portal. Well, I found how to do it. I started and run a liferay project, which landed me on the starting welcome page(after signing in). Then I went to add option(on top right side)/more/ typed 'iframe' in search field.

Thus I am able to add the iframe and I just need to configure it, by giving the url which I wanna visit. This url can be any servers landing page or any url.

Answer (score 2):

An iFrame is a HTML frame on your page that allows you to display a page at a different URL within your page.

So if you're using an iframe you can supply it with a URL to point to the application page you want to include on the page.

So it would be something like:

```
<iframe id=​"someiframeid" src=​"http:​/​/path/to/other/page" height=​"500" name=""></iframe>
```

You may want to add more properties to your iframe and these can be [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Is there any more information you need? 
​

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src='your/application/url.php'></iframe>
```

Can you give more information on what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="myIFrame"  src="about:blank" longdesc="url" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

I prefere these way, the attribute longdesc contain the url of the page, these prevent auto loading when the main page is open, you ca une js for open the url in the IFrame.